# Select individual form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('form["meldaan"] input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form["meldaan"] input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

This script works fine with one form, but I have two or three different forms on one page. I want each form to be treated different, if I use this code all fields in ALL forms need to be filled in, which I obviously don't want.

How can I identify the unique forms? Say one form is named `name="formone"` and the other `name="formtwo"`. How would I implement that? (It's okay if I have to make more functions).

Comment: Why won't you give ids to your `<form>`??

Comment: @gdoron you could, but names are more usual on forms and form elements.

Comment: @Christophe. Nonsense. id as much as I'm aware of can be used for any HTML tag. and "usual" ? usual if you need to select individual item when you have multiple, you give it id...

Comment: @gdoron wrong, id cannot be used on any HTML tag. But anyway that was not my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to adjust your selector:

```
$('form[name="formone"] > input')
```

Update: @Andre, in your live example inputs are not direct children of the form element, so you need to use:

```
$('form[name="formone"] input')
```

Update 2: if you are using an id:

```
$('#formid input')
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.. Strange. I tried it with ID too, but that didn't work as well.

Comment: @gdoron what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Christophe live demo at http://www.websiteuniversiteit.nl/new/ , Aanmelden is the first form and inloggen the second.

Comment: @gdoron added that but still doesn't work :( the live website is http://www.websiteuniversiteit.nl/new , aanmelden is the form.

Comment: @Christophe .. still not working.. See my updated post for the code I have at this point

Comment: @Andre your code is not correct, take a closer look at my answer.

Comment: @Christophe what is not correct exactly? I used the one without the > both times, that's correct right?